# Installation error with ipython on macbook

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to install ipython on my macbook using command `$ sudo easy_install ipython`

Before that I have installed brew.

But when i install ipython command, i am getting the following error:

```
error: Setup script exited with error in ipython setup command: Invalid environment marker: sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
```

Could someone help me how to solve this? I need to develop project quickly.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: You should really consider a package manager like MacPorts (older and probably has a few more repositories) or Homebrew (more recent and people have reported much better experience on this one).

Comment: Remember that MacPorts uses a different folder to store its stuff. So when you are installing something using pip, you will first need to install the MacPorts version of pip, and then do a proper linking of pip.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue, solved it by upgrading pip, try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then retry installing ipython:

```
pip install ipython
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed ipython via pip and everything works great.

```
sudo pip install ipython
```

To install **pip** I used **easy_install**

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

There are more specific information on [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/get_started/os_setup.html#source)